# retrofit response.body!! Kotlin android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, jsonapi-resources

I have a problem with a retrofit with Kotlin the code is as follows:

```
MainActivity.kt

 val apiInterface = ApiInterface.create().getCountry()
        apiInterface.enqueue( object : Callback<List<data>>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<data>>?, response: Response<List<data>>?) {
                if(response?.body() != null){
                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,response.body()!!)

                    binding.spCountry.adapter=adapter //spCountry is a spinner
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<data>>?, t: Throwable?) {}
        })
```

ApiInterface.kt

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/v3.1/all")
    fun getCountry() : Call<List<data>>
    companion object {
        var BASE_URL = "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all/"
        fun create() : ApiInterface {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

data.kt

```
data class data(
    @SerializedName("name") val name: name
)
data class name(
    @SerializedName("common") val common: String
)
```

The result I get is this in the spinner and I just want the name of the country

[image]

Comment: So you want to convert your `List<data>` to `List<String>`, right?

Comment: yes, I want to show it in the spinner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a simple `map` operation to convert your `List<data>` to `List<String>`.

```kotlin
val originalList: List<data> = // Response from retrofit
val newList: List<String> = originalList.map { it.name.common }
```

[try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/khbmIUaJX)